# Check if another workbook contains a sheet with a certain name

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a macro to check if a workbook contains a sheet with a certain name.
Here is the best I can make at the moment :

```
Function IsSheetExist(Year As Integer, Month As Integer) As Boolean
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim shtName As String

'creat the target sheetname (201901 / 201902 / 201903 / ... / 201912)
If Month < 10 Then
    shtName = Year & "0" & Month
Else
    shtName = Year & Month
End If

'Cells(1,1) is the folderPath and Cells(4,1) is the fileName
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Cells(1, 1) & "/" & Cells(4, 1))

For Each sht In wb.Worksheets
    If sht.Name = shtName Then
        IsSheetExist = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next sht
IsSheetExist = False
MsgBox ("It seems that the sheet [" + shtName + "] is not present in the workbook - " + Cells(4, 1))
End Function
```

This code didn't work yet, but maybe with some help it will ?

PS : I don"t want open the workbook target, just check its sheets names

Comment: If you open the worbook you should close it after: `wb.Close SaveChanges:=False`. Your code looks fine to me, what exactly is the issue? Any errors?

Comment: thanks  Pᴇʜ you find the solution ! 
because I didn't close the workbook once opened, the following operations search the paths and filenames of the following workbooks in the one that was just opened and does not have this information.

Comment: Then make use of absolute references like `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")` instead of just `Range("A1")` to avoid strange behaviour of your code. It is highly recommend to tell VBA for every range, cells, columns, rows, etc object in which workbook and worksheet you expect it. Otherwise Excel guesses which one it is and it takes the one that has foucs which might be the wrong one.

Comment: ok good to know, I will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign CheckSheetExist = True, you need to change that to your function name for it to actually return

So instead use:

```
IsSheetExist = True
```

(And same for where you assign it = False)

[although I'd tend to assign it false before you enter the "for each sht..." loop, but it wouldn't matter here]

Ran it here, works OK. Now, I'd include

```
wb.Close saveChanges :=False
```

just before both potential exit points, otherwise next time you run, if wb isn't closed you'll get a 1004 error

Comment: thanks I just edit my post, it was a copy/past mistake but not the the reason of my issue

Comment: I would even open the file `ReadOnly:=True` since it is not panned to save any changes. Checkout the [Workbooks.Open method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open)

Comment: Good shout PEH - readOnly :=True is an excellent way to avoid inadvertent changes! Belt & Braces!

Answer (score 1):

Easier function for this...

```
Function WorkSheetExists(ByVal wb As Workbook, ByVal strName As String) As Boolean
   On Error Resume Next
   WorkSheetExists = Not wb.Worksheets(strName) Is Nothing
End Function
```